# Zooming in chrome without changing font or layout

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-extensions

We all know how zooming in chrome works, the fonts and the layout also changes.
i have been looking for a solution to this. 
and found this extension [Custom Page Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-page-zoom/jodiabicmogcbbiocceenmeflipeelle?hl=en)

this extension works as expected, but the problem is that it doesn't have shortcuts.
i was wondering if there was another solutions to this, or may be have an idea on how could this be implemented.

Comment: For help with questions, suggestions, or problems, visit the developer's support site.https://mybrowseraddon.com/custom-page-zoom.html

Comment: Yeah, I've reached out to him, waiting for a response.